# Adjusting payoff diagram for call option

Tags: finance

If the payoff for a 2 year European call option is 
(S2 - K) x I(S2>K)
K is the strike price, which in this case is £90
I is the indicator function, so if S2>K then I(S2>K)=1, 0 otherwise 
S2 is the share price at time 2
S0 is the initial share price = £100
How would one adjust a call payoff diagram for a derivative with payoff
(S2-G) x I(S2>K)
where G is a constant such that there is no upfront price? I have calculated G as 125.142857
Strike price remains at £90